# Add two columns from two tables and insert result into third

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL is not my area of expertise, so please bear with me.

I’m using Veeam backup and replication, I need a running backup success percentage, unfortunately Veeam, doesn't provide one.

Veeam has a SQL table called “Bjobs” (I know!) it has columns for “Name” and “Latest_Result” where latest result = 0 for success.

I've created a new table called “Bjobs_history” with columns for “Name” “Success_Total” “Job_Total” and “Percentage_Success”

My plan is to create a SQL query to add "1" to the “Job_total” column each time the job runs, this bit I think I can do.

I then want to add 1 to the “Success_Total” only if the job succeeds. I can then calculate the percentage against those two results.

So if I had JobA and JobB both running each day for 5 days and JobA is successful each day, but JobB fails once, my table would look like this

```
Name | Success_Total | Job_total

JobA |     5         |   5

JobB |     4         |   5
```

Since the Latest_result = 0 when successful, I’ll need to add 1 to this result then add this to the “Success_total” column.

This is what I have to update the success_total, which isn't working, can anyone help?

```
select latest_result + 1 as val1
from bjobs join bjob_history
on (bjobs.name = BJob_History.name)
where latest_result = 0
update BJob_History  set Success_Total = val1
```

Comment: What isn't working about it (i.e. do you see any error messages)?  Those would help us help you.  Is the update step failing?  If you don't try to update, but only run the select, do you get the right result?

Comment: Hi. Sorry the error says -  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'val1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE BH
SET BH.Success_Total = BH.Success_Total + B.latest_result + 1
FROM BJob_History AS BH
INNER JOIN bjobs AS B
    ON B.name = BH.name
WHERE B.latest_result = 0
```

Comment: Thanks a million, worked a treat! I'll try and figure out exactly how that statement works now :)

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon, this works the first time, but I need it to run each day and for the "Success_Total" value to increase by 1 for each successful backup. That's why I was trying to total up success_total + latest_result + 1 as success_total in the original query I wrote - which obviously didn't work.

Comment: Well, I think this answers to your question. I don't understand what you are saying, try to explain better. Maybe posting some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: The "latest_result" column, if the job is successful will always = 0. Your statement adds 1 to this value and then applies to the "success_total" column, so the "success_total" column = 1. I need this query to run each day and add to the "success_total" column if the job is successful on that day, so assuming it was successful the "success_total" would = 2 the next day and 3 the day after that. I can then use that value and compare it to the actual amount of times the job has run to create a percentage of success. I'll try and expand the original post a little more too. thanks again 4 the help

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

@king.code

I just added an extra bit to your statement and its working now, thanks

```
UPDATE BH
SET BH.Success_Total = BH.Success_Total + B.latest_result + 1
FROM BJob_History AS BH
INNER JOIN bjobs AS B
ON B.name = BH.name
WHERE B.latest_result = 0
```